# How to use the same network as the parent container (Docker in Docker)?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, rabbitmq, docker-network

I have a docker-compose file that includes the following services:

- Dind (where inside this container there are other containers responsible for consuming a RabbitMQ queue)
- RabbitMQ

I would like the child containers of Dind to consume messages from the RabbitMQ within the same docker-compose file as Dind.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  dind:
    build:
      context: docker-compose-command-api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: docker-compose-command-api
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./message-consumer-worker:/app/message-consumer-worker:ro
    networks:
      - default

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.12.10-management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=guest
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=guest
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    volumes:
      - ./rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf:ro
      - ./rabbitmq/definitions.json:/etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json:ro
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "rabbitmqctl", "status" ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 5
    networks:
      - default

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
```

The docker-compose that will run inside the Dind:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: message-consumer-worker
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: message-consumer-worker
```

From what I researched, it would be possible to use an external network. However, I didn't implement it due to a lack of knowledge.

I'm running Docker in Docker (DinD) because inside it, I have an API responsible for scaling consumers. For instance, the API receives a request to scale up 10 consumers, and then it creates containers using the 'docker compose up' command. That's why I need to run Docker in Docker to make my consumers scalable. Do you have any other suggestions that could help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `network_mode: host` in the docker-compose file. This will make the inside container use the same network of the host (outside container).

Answer (score 0):

A Docker network is specific to an instance of the Docker daemon.  If you're running a Docker-in-Docker setup, the nested Docker daemon has its own images, containers, volumes, and networks; you can't share any of these resources between the two Dockers.  Compose `external: true` networks allow one Compose file to attach to networks created outside this specific Compose file, but not in other Docker daemons.  The [Docker Hub `docker` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker) doesn't obviously provide anything like the `host.docker.internal` host name available on Docker Desktop to call out to the daemon's network environment.

The easiest answer here is to run the RabbitMQ broker and worker in the same Compose file.  You don't need a nested Docker daemon here, and I might delete the DinD container entirely.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  rabbitmq: { ... }
  app:
    build: message-consumer-worker
```

Comment: A remark I forgot to mention: I'm running Docker in Docker (DinD) because inside it, I have an API responsible for scaling consumers. For instance, the API receives a request to scale up 10 consumers, and then it creates containers using the 'docker compose up' command. That's why I need to run Docker in Docker to make my consumers scalable. Do you have any other suggestions that could help me?

Comment: If you _really_ need to directly manage Docker containers, the general advice I've seen is to give your application access to the host's Docker socket; then you're using the same Docker, and can share a Compose network.  But, this has some significant security concerns, and it means your application is tightly bound to Docker in a way that won't work with, for example, Kubernetes.